# how can I get to <li> nested inside <ul> nested inside multiple <div> tags in powershell

Tags: powershell, web-scraping

Here is the HTML code that I want to take info from

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="classifiedDetail">
     <div class="classifiedDetail">
       <div class="classifiedDetailContent">
         <div class="classifiedInfo">
           <ul class="classifiedInfoList">
             <li>
                <strong>Number</strong>&nbsp;
                <span class="classifiedId" id="classifiedId">434599923</span>
            </li>
            <li>
               <strong>Date</strong>&nbsp;
               <span> 30-9-2017 </span>
           </li>
           <li>
              <strong>Number of cards</strong>&nbsp;
              <span class=""> 23 </span>
           </li>
           <li>
              <strong>Number of cubes</strong>&nbsp;
              <span class=""> 0 </span>
           </li>
         </ul>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to access to the third `<li>` tag. I want to take out the number `23` from the `<span>`

Here is what I tried

```
$subPage = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $someLink
$temp = $subPage.ParsedHtml.body.getElementsByTagName('div') | 
  Where-Object{$_.className -eq 'classifiedinfo'} | 
  Where {$_.getElementsByTagName('ul')} | 
  Where_Object {$_.className -eq 'classifiedInfoList'} | 
  Where {$_.getElementsByTagName('li')} | 
  Where {$_.getElementsByTagName('span')} |
  Where-Object {$_.className -eq ''}
```

I'm trying to `$temp | Out-File temp.txt` to see the results but it gives me nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Use `querySelector` to get the first matching element:

  ```
  $text = $subPage.ParsedHtml.querySelector(
      '.classifiedInfo .classifiedInfoList li span[class=""]').textContent
  ```
- Use `querySelectorAll` to get all matching elements' text:

  ```
  function qsa($req, $selector) {
      $collection = $req.ParsedHtml.querySelectorAll($selector)
      foreach ($i in 0..($collection.length - 1)) { $collection.item($i) }
  }

  $req = Invoke-WebRequest http://localhost/test.html
  $text = (qsa $req '.classifiedInfo .classifiedInfoList li span[class=""]').textContent
  ```

Note, class name in these functions is case-sensitive.